# Updating Scheduled Task Script from Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, scheduled-tasks

I'm attempting to write a Powershell script that runs once a day. One of the many functions it will perform is to make sure that the script itself is up to date. My problem is that since I version the scripts, I need to update the scheduled task I create from within the script.

I've thought about 2 different approaches here, of which I can't figure out either:

1. I initially thought I could simply get the ScheduledTask object for my Task, and update the file path there. I was ultimately unable to access the path.
2. My next thought was I could simply call `Unregister-ScheduledTask -TaskName "mytask"` and then afterwards Register-ScheduledTask and recreate it with the new path.

After failing Option 1, I'm stuck on the execution of Option 2. I am able to find and Unregister my Task, but when attempting to register it with the new path I receive the following error:

```
Register-ScheduledJob : The scheduled job definition <myTask> already exists in the job definition store.
At line:3 char:1
+ Register-ScheduledJob -Name "<myTask>" -FilePath "C:\Apps\\Uploade ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Microsoft.Power...edJobDefinition:ScheduledJobDefinition) [Register-ScheduledJob], ScheduledJobException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CantRegisterScheduledJobDefinition,Microsoft.PowerShell.ScheduledJob.RegisterScheduledJobCommand
```

**Edit**:
To clarify, my Scheduled task path is something like, C:\Apps\myscript_v0.0.1.ps1 As a result, when I update, it will become C:\Apps\myscript_v0.1.5.ps1 or whatever, and I need to run the new version as opposed to old one that is currently the target.

Comment: Why not keep the path to the live script constant, and track version history elsewhere? < Why does the path need to change?

Comment: @noam Added clarification, see my edit

Comment: Do you have a scheduled task, or a scheduled job? [Click here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/11/23/using-scheduled-tasks-and-scheduled-jobs-in-powershell.aspx) for more info (The Scripting Guys blog link).

Comment: @TheMadTechnician I cannot believe I messed that up, thank you for catching that. I had registered a Job, but unregistered a Task and tried reregistering another job which obviously doesnt work haha. I'll leave this up in hopes someone might provide a solution to simply updating the file without jumping through registration hoops. Just in case if you want to add your comment as an answer I can accept it in a few days if there are no other bites.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, changing the job's file path is easy. First we get the job, then we pipe that scheduledjob object to Set-ScheduledJob and specify the -FilePath

```
$NewPath = GCI C:\Apps\myscript_*.ps1 | Select -last 1 -ExpandProperty FullName
Get-ScheduledJob MyJob | Set-ScheduledJob -FilePath $NewPath
```

**Edit:** To give credit where credit is due, I would like to thank `Get-Help *-ScheduledJob` followed by `Get-Help Set-ScheduledJob -Full` and Example 1 for going through this exact situation...

> ```
> Example 1: Change the script that a job runs
>
> The first command uses the Get-ScheduledJob cmdlet to get the Inventory 
> scheduled job. The output shows that the job runs the Get-Inventory.ps1 
> script.This command is not required; it is included only to show the 
> effect of the script change.
>
> PS C:\>Get-ScheduledJob -Name Inventory
> Id         Name            Triggers        Command                                  Enabled
> --         ----            --------        -------                                  -------
> 1          Inventory       {1}             C:\Scripts\Get-Inventory.ps1             True
>
> The second command uses the Get-ScheduledJob cmdlet to get the Inventory
> scheduled job. A pipeline operator (|) sends the scheduled job to the 
> Set-ScheduledJob cmdlet. The Set-ScheduledJob command uses the Script 
> parameter to specify a new script, Get-FullInventory.ps1. The command
> uses the Passthru parameter to return the scheduled job after the change.
>
> PS C:\>Get-ScheduledJob -Name Inventory | Set-ScheduledJob -FilePath C:\Scripts\Get-FullInventory.ps1 -Passthru
> ```

Comment: Welp now I feel like an idiot. Always good to learn something new haha! Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1):

Just posting as PowerShell was updated to include `Unregister-ScheduledJob` as seen [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Hh849771.aspx)