# How to update a Windows Task Scheduler task from an updater/script running as admin

Tags: windows, windows-task-scheduler

I'm writing an updater for my application and want to change my "Windows Task Scheduler" task configured by:

```
schtasks /create /sc once /tn my_task /tr MyApp.exe /rl highest /st 00:00
```

The updater is running "with highest privileges" and I mainly want to change the path of `MyApp.exe`.

I've tried:

- `schtasks /Change /tn my_task /tr MyUpdatedApp.exe` (But it asks: `Please enter the run as password for...` even though the script already runs as admin. And so is not user friendly or even working in my scripted update.)
- [A powershell script using `Get-/Set-ScheduledJob`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25515795/1937795) (But it says: `A scheduled job definition with Name my_task could not be found`. The help text even states `Although jobs that are created by using the Register-ScheduledJob cmdlet appear in Task Scheduler, Get-ScheduledJob gets only scheduled jobs. It does not get scheduled tasks created in Task Scheduler.`)

How can I updated my scheduled task from my updater/script without user interaction?

Answer (score 1):

I've resorted to exporting and recreating the task using an XML file with the following command:

```
schtasks /create /f /tn my_task /xml C:\somewhere\my_task.xml
```

I create the `my_task.xml` file by exporting it by hand in the GUI and storing it as part of my application.